# confusion on a statement about truth

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I have to prove the following: $$(\exists x) \phi \to (\exists x)\psi \vDash (\exists x)(\phi\to\psi)$$ and prove the the opposite direction is wrong. However i think i ve misunderstood something cause i think it s the other way around.
What i have tried is: (I ll use "a" instead of gothic a to save some time here, meaning an L-structure).

Let $a\vDash (\exists x) \phi \to (\exists x)\psi $, so we have $a\vDash (\exists x) \phi \Rightarrow a\vDash(\exists x)(\psi) $, thus [$a\vDash \phi(c_a)$ for some $ a \in A \Rightarrow a\vDash \psi(c_b)$ for some  $b\in A$] but from here we cannot infer that $a \vDash \psi (c_a)$. Instead if we have the opposite direction we have that if

$a\vDash (\exists x)(\phi\to\psi)$ then..... $a\vDash \phi(c_a) \rightarrow \psi(c_a)$ for some $a \in A$ and thus $a \vDash(\exists x) \phi \to (\exists x)\psi $

What am i doing wrong here? Could you also provide a counterexample to get a better understanding?

Comment: In a model $\{ a, b \}$ where $\psi$ is false on both $[x:=a]$ and $[x:=b]$ but $\phi$ is true for $[x:=a]$ and false for $[x:=b]$, the right hand side is satisfied (with witness $b$) but the left hand side is not satisfied (since $(\exists x)\phi$ is satisfied with witness $a$ while $(\exists x)\psi$ is not satisfied).

Comment: I think you'll have to make use of the assumption that the universe of discourse is nonempty - otherwise, for an empty universe of discourse, the left hand side is satisfied ($F \rightarrow F$) but the right hand side is not.  You'll probably also need to use excluded middle somewhere in the argument.

Comment: Your counterexample does not quite work i think because the argument says that there exists x....not for all x.....you chose x=a to make the contradiction but for x=b  the left hand side still stands, does it not? So indeed there $(\exists x)\phi(x) \Rightarrow (\exists x) \psi$.....etc

Comment: I was interpreting the left hand side as $((\exists x) \phi) \rightarrow ((\exists x) \psi)$, not $(\exists x) (\phi \rightarrow ((\exists x) \psi))$ since the latter has issues with "local variable shadowing".  So as I said, in my model $(\exists x) \phi$ is true but $(\exists x) \psi$ is false.

Comment: aah yeah sorry my bad you re absolutely correct. Very nice example it helps a lot clear things out. I think i understand now in what part i was wrong in the proof. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You have it backwards alright. What if  $\phi$ is $(x=0\land x\ne 1)$ and if $\psi$  is $(x=1\land x \ne 0)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints for one possible approach to the forward argument: assuming the universe of discourse $\mathfrak{a}$ is nonempty, let $x_0$ be an object in $\mathfrak{a}$.  The proof will then have two cases, based on whether or not $\mathfrak{a} \models \phi[x:=x_0]$:

1. Suppose $\mathfrak{a} \models \phi[x := x_0]$.  Then $\mathfrak{a} \models (\exists x) \phi$, so $\mathfrak{a} \models (\exists x) \psi$.  Let $y_0$ be a witness, so that $\mathfrak{a} \models \psi[x := y_0]$.  Now, why does it follow that $\mathfrak{a} \models \exists x (\phi \rightarrow \psi)$?
2. Suppose $\mathfrak{a} \models \lnot \phi[x := x_0]$.  Then you can immediately conclude $\mathfrak{a} \models \exists x (\phi \rightarrow \psi)$ (why?).

For a counterexample for the reverse direction: as indicated earlier in the comments, use the model where the universe of discourse is $\{ a, b \}$, with:
$$ \mathfrak{a} \models \phi[x := a], \lnot \psi[x := a], \lnot \phi[x := b], \lnot \psi[x := b]. $$
Then the right hand side is satisfied (with witness $b$); however, the left hand side is not satisfied, since $(\exists x) \phi$ is satisfied with witness $a$, while $(\exists x) \psi$ is not satisfied.